# Centering fluid div having max-width

Tags: centering, fluid-layout, css

I'm trying to center my content div. It's set to 100%, and the div is contained in body, which is also set to 100%. I have a max-width: 1400px because I don't want my content to stretch more than that if the screen resolution is higher. The thing is, it doesn't work using margin: auto. My content stands on the left, uncentered on screen wider than 1400px.

If I delete the max-width, everything is perfectly centered on wide screens, but the content is stretched to the the whole screen...

```
#content {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 50px;
display: none;
max-width: 1400px;
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this, is to set the `width` property to the max width you need, and add `max-width: 100%;`. This will prevent it from being bigger than 100% but still go up to the max width. Also, you should remove the `absolute` positioning:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nacMP/24/)

Comment: Or simply `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `transform` technique, which doesn't require extra mark-up or media queries.

```
#content {
    position: relative;  /* 'fixed' will work also. */
    max-width: 500px;    /* Your required width here. */
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/matharden/6uduf7av/

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox...

Put this classes in the parent element (the body):

The HTML

```
<body class="p-flexbox flex-hcc">
 <!-- The content -->
</body>
```

Where:

1. **p-flexbox** means *parent-flexbox*
2. **flex-hcc** means *flexbox-horizontal-center-center*

The CSS

```
.p-flexbox {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: box;
}

.flex-hcc {

   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
   -webkit-box-align: center;

   -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
   -moz-box-pack: center;
   -moz-box-align: center;

   box-orient: horizontal;
   box-pack: center;
   box-align: center;
```

}

Cheers,
Leonardo